# AngularJS enter url directly into browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

What's possible to load content by url from browser when someone comming from somewhere? I don't want use ng-view with ngRoute. Look here http://kangaroom.net/ when you search e.g. Glasgow - you should see new url in the browser. They don't have any ng-view in DOM. But when you put link directly into browser: http://kangaroom.net/room/search?exp=Glasgow&lat=55.864237&lon=-4.251805999999988&countryId=76 you should see the same result. What it's possible?

Comment: I think it's called the [History API](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/).

Comment: @AustinMullins I don't think, because popstate don't listen first load page. This is fired only when you click "previous page" in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use a ngRoute like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:page', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl1'
});
```

And in the MyCtrl1 on begin I have switch case $routeParams and use action.

Answer (score 0):

Check out angular's $location service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

From `/search/?query=hello` you can access query params from the url using

```
$location.search('query')
// => hello
```